# SQL Server returns identical by LEN() and DATALENGTH() and Font Case string values as being not matched using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, inner-join, string-matching

I have the following query written to check is all the columns string values are matched. But I'm returning the a lot of records that are identical by LEN() and DATALENGTH() functions and with the same font case parameter. Please review it and let me know if you've ever experienced this anomaly. 
Note, that the Table1 and Table2 columns Data Types being joined in the query below are the same: [ID] - int null and [Designation] - nvarchar(255) null. 
Both of the tables are located on the same Server and the same Database.

Cannot attach the result set of the query below. So, ping me and I can email it to you allowing you to test it yourself. That is Excel file of 15.4 KB. Thanks everyone in advance for every tip given.

[image: Matching string values are not matched using INNER JOIN]

```
SELECT 
A.ID, O.ID, 
A.[Designation], 
O.[Designation],
LEN( A.[Designation]) AS [STRING LENGTH_1],
LEN(O.[Designation]) AS [STRING LENGTH_2],
DATALENGTH(A.[Designation]) AS [STRING DATA TYPE LENGTH_1],
DATALENGTH( O.[Designation]) AS [STRING DATA TYPE LENGTH_2]
FROM [Project].[Table1] A WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [Project].[Table2] O WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON A.ID = O.ID 
AND
A.[Desigmation] != O.[Designation];
```

Comment: are there extra space or return carriages present in this data?

Comment: No, there are no.